# Stopping "Not responding"

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a backup process copying a lot of files (CopyFileEx) and every few minutes, windows seems to need a break, probably paging-out or clearing buffers or something. During this time, the main form blinks and displays "Not responding" in the main Caption.

After a few seconds it blinks again, the message has gone and all is well with the World and the process continues.

Is there some way I can stop the blink and message?

Comment: Run the file copy out of a different thread so that you don't block the main thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, but I have never used threads and not sure I want to get into that just for this one application. I am doing this as freebie for a friend and at age 74, not really interested in the "thread" learning curve. I tried a file-copy unit that used threads but the PC could be shut down because it looked to the operator that the process had finished, but in fact the thread was still hammering away in the background.

Comment: Using a thread for this is the one and only solution. If you don't want to use threads then you'll have to accept a frozen UI.

Answer (score 7):

"Not Responding" has a very specific meaning: *The application's UI thread is not continuing to pump messages.*  The reason Windows calls this "Not Responding" is because the message pump is what sends user input to the application for your code to respond to.  Once you understand this, the way to keep the application responsive is obvious: don't run long, blocking operations in the UI thread. Actually implementing that can be tricky, for two reasons.

First, feedback:  If you're doing a long operation in a separate thread, you want it to report back to the user on its progress, which can only be done in the UI thread.  So you need to use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` [or something similar](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) (shameless self-promotion) to post back UI updates to your main thread.

Second, if you have a "copy everything" button in the UI, and it takes a minute to run, and it's running on a different thread but you're keeping the main thread responsive, what's stopping the user from clicking the "copy everything" button again before the task is complete?  This may or may not be a valid operation according to your program design, but it it isn't, it can cause problems.  Make sure that, if this can be a problem, that your design compensates for it, for example by disabling the button after you click it and re-enabling it after it completes.

Finally, if you're going to do anything complex at all with multithreading,  I'd highly recommend you take a good look at [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)... except that the tag says you're using Delphi 5, which can't run OTL.  You really ought to take a look at updating.